# Why does this code take up so much memory?

Tags: algorithm, python, optimization

I created a solution to [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-dna-sequences/) problem on leetcode:

> All DNA is composed of a series of nucleotides abbreviated as A, C, G, and T, for example: "ACGAATTCCG". When studying DNA, it is sometimes useful to identify repeated sequences within the DNA.
>
> Write a function to find all the 10-letter-long sequences (substrings) that occur more than once in a DNA molecule.

My solution causes an **out of memory exception**:

```
class Solution:
    # @param {string} s
    # @return {string[]}
    def findRepeatedDnaSequences(self, s):
        seen_so_far = set()
        results = set()
        for seq in self.window(10, s):
            if seq in seen_so_far:
                results.add(seq)
            else:
                seen_so_far.add(seq)
        return list(results)

    def window(self, window_size, array):
        window_start = 0
        window_end = window_size
        while window_end < len(array):
            yield array[window_start:window_end+1]
            window_end += window_size
```

**This solution works:**

```
class Solution:
    # @param {string} s
    # @return {string[]}
    def findRepeatedDnaSequences(self, s):
        d = {}
        res = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            key = s[i:i+10]
            if key not in d:
                d[key] = 1
            else:
                d[key] += 1

        for e in d:
            if d[e] > 1:
                res.append(e)

        return res
```

**They seem essentially the same. What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `window` function is incorrect. It yields a sequence of substrings `[0:11]`, `[0:21]`, `[0:31]`, ... (note that `window_start` remains zero). It can be fixed e.g. as

```
def window(self, window_size, array):
    window_start = 0
    while window_start < len(array) - window_size + 1:
        yield array[window_start:window_start+window_size]
        window_start += 1
```

*Edit:* substring ending indices were off by 1.

Comment: Yeah, important fix in this one: only increment by one or won't find substrings that don't match your 10-character-jumps boundaries...

Answer (score 3):

In this:

```
def window(self, window_size, array):
    window_start = 0
    window_end = window_size
    while window_end < len(array):
        yield array[window_start:window_end+1]
        window_end += window_size
```

the value of `window_start` is never changed.  So, given that `window_size` is 10, you first yield the slice `0:11` (but wanted `0:10`), then the slice `0:21` (but wanted `1:11`), then the slice `0:31` (but wanted `2:12`), and so on.  The total length of all the slices you return grows proportionally to the **square** of `len(array)`.  If `array` is long, that would explain it.  But not enough info was given to be sure about that.